# Python socket - issues taking ip, takes it as a string

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp, ip

Been trying to solve this simple script, without luck. The error I got is the following:

python renato_script.py

Enter HOSTNAME ip: 10.0.0.2

Enter TCP/UDP port: 443

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "renato_script.py", line 8, in

if s.connect_ex((ip, port)):

TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

```
import socket


ip = input( "Enter HOSTNAME ip: ")
port = input ("Enter TCP/UDP port: ")

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
if s.connect_ex((ip, port)):
        print ("Port", port, "is closed")
else:
        print ("Port", port, "is open")
```

Comment: Write `int(port)` instead of port, which is a string. Port must be an int

Comment: its getting worse:

python renato_script.py
  File "renato_script.py", line 5
    int(port) = input ("Enter TCP/UDP port: ")
    ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Comment: You can't do a function to the left side of an assignment. You need to cast the right side, like `int(input("Enter ..."))`. See my answer for more context.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html, the AF_INET address family needs a tuple which contains a string ip address and a integer port. Your code passes a tuple which contains a string ip address and string port. Fixing that is very simple, just cast the port to int, like this:

```
port = int(raw_input("Enter TCP/UDP port: "))
```

edit: when using python 2, you have to use raw_input() rather than input()

Comment: I believe that helped, but seems like the IP is actually the problem:

Comment: I believe that helped, but seems like the IP is actually the problem:

python renato_script.py
Enter HOSTNAME ip: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "renato_script.py", line 4, in ?
    ip = input( "Enter HOSTNAME ip: ")
  File "<string>", line 1
    XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
              ^

Comment: python renato_script.py

Enter HOSTNAME ip: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "renato_script.py", line 4, in ?

    ip = input( "Enter HOSTNAME ip: ")

  File "<string>", line 1

    XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

              ^

Comment: @agusbava You are using python 3, not python 2 right?

Comment: running it on Python 2.4.3 (#1, Oct 23 2012, 22:02:41)

Comment: @agusbava when using python 2, you have to use raw_input() rather than input()